# Ember (belongsTo and hasMany) association not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

It always returns null, when I tried with another 'find' call it returns me a promised array, which is useless for me. I can't use it as a relation in views.

```
App.Truck = DS.Model.extend
  job: DS.belongsTo('job', { async: true })

App.Job = DS.Model.extend
  trucks: DS.hasMany('truck', { embedded: 'always' })
```

Comment: Can you post where/how you're trying to obtain the records? You're using `embedded` which implies that you're going to send `trucks` inside the response to `job/:id` in your API, so if your job response doesn't contain the trucks records, it would be null. Ember won't try to make a request to get them since it expects them to be embedded when you get the `belongsTo` record.

Comment: Thanks @tom, now I have both set as async: true
trucks: DS.hasMany('truck', { async: true }), it shows in Ember Inspector that Truck has the PromisedObject of Job, and Job has Trucks as PromisedManyArray.
But in views when I do truck.get('job') it does not let me access the data, in console.log it shows the data..

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I got it working.

There were few issues in my understandings of Ember's Data association/relationship and how this Ember data works. The point the @tom raised here for

```
embedded: 'always'
```

pointed me into the right direction. I never needed embedded for trucks on Job, all I needed was to ensure when I call truck I should have the job associated with it, so I used

```
async: true
```

on both ends, truck and job.

Then there was an issue with accessing the data, I was getting a Promised object and that needs

```
truck.get('job').then (job) ->
   job.get('jobName')
```

So this is how I got what I needed. There are still few things that needs to be done, but I think I will get it done now.